# Image not updated with Meioupload

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, meio-upload

I just recently started using MeioUpload 2.0 with cakephp 1.3.
Ive configured the behaviour correctly with my model and im able to upload images with my model correctly.

But when i try to edit the same model and change the picture to another one, the picture is not uploading and i'm getting the validation error of "Invalid file type".

Please anyone can guide me where i'm doing something wrong.

Comment: The issue is resolved.
The problem was on my edit form. It didn't have a type property set to file.
e.g. 
echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'edit','class'=>'main_form','type' => 'file'));

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. The problem was on my edit form. It didn't have a type property set to file. e.g. echo $this->Form->create('User',array('action'=>'edit','class'=>'main_form','type' => 'file'));